# How can I test my server response time?

Tags: performance, performance-monitoring

I'd like to test my server response time and how fast my website loads. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add all of the relevant requirements to your question and then flag to have it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Use developer tools in chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, but is there any way to test it in different terminals at the same time? even if its payed?

Comment: @Jose-kusunoki: Now you've changed the goalposts. What do you mean by different terminals? Don't answer that here, look at how crappy your original question is then consider how you can improve it by adding all of the relevant information by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at web-based services like [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) or [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) to cut your own home/workspace link speed out of the equation.
Those tools will also give you hints on what exactly is slow or costs time.